# after"" node exampleScript.js "" ,cant write in cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i got 2 scripts in folder "my",and in folder node_modules is mongodb folder installed.

code 1 :

```
   var mongo=require("mongodb");
var host= "127.0.0.1";
var port=mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;
var db= new mongo.Db("nodejs-introduction",new mongo.Server(host,port,{}), {safe: false})
db.open(function(error){


    console.log("we are connected" + " "+ host + ":" + port);

db.collection("user",function(error,collection){

    console.log("we got collection");


   collection.insert({
   id:"1",
   name:"Lauris Skraucis",
   twitter:"LauroSkr",
   email:"skciz@gmail.com",

},function(){

    console.log("sucessfully inserted Lauris")
});



collection.insert({
   id:"1",
   name:"Janis Skraucis",
   twitter:"Jask",
   email:"jask_dosiba@inbox.lv",

},function(){

    console.log("sucessfully inserted Janis")
});



});

});
```

and 2nd file

```
var mongo=require("mongodb");
var host= "127.0.0.1";
var port=mongo.Connection.DEFAULT_PORT;
var db= new mongo.Db("nodejs-introduction",new mongo.Server(host,port,{}));
db.open(function(error){


   console.log("we are connected" + " "+ host + ":" + port);

db.collection("user",function(error,collection){

   collection.find({"id:1"},function(error,cursor){
       cursor.toArray(function(error,users){
             if(users.length==0){
                 console.log("no user");
             }else{

console.log("found user",users[0]);
             }
       });
   });

});

});
```

after i write in cmd cd C:\Users\X\Desktop\my , then node the 1st file,i get

we are connected 127.0.0.1:27017
we got collection
sucessfully inserted Lauris
sucessfully inserted Janis

after that i cant write anything in cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your app is running and waiting any interaction to log your data.

if you want to exit the app :  ctrl+c
if you want to run the app and be able to write in cmd :

- open another cmd :)
- run node using a compiler like netbeans or eclipse or even sublime-text